# Can we deduce this property for 2 norm with respect to sub matrix of Cholesky factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, spectral-norm, cholesky-decomposition

We have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which is symmetric and positive-definite. Also, $A$ is a block matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{21}^{\top} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

We can then obtain a block Cholesky factorization,

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} L_{11} & 0 \\ L_{21} &L_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} L_{11}^{\top} & L_{21}^{\top} \\0  &L_{22}^{\top} \\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

Is it true that,
$$\|L_{22}\|_{2} \le \|A\|_{2}?$$

I don't think it is.

Comment: if you mean the $A_{ij}$ to be squares of the same size, write $A \in \mathbb R^{2n \times 2n}$    and somehow indicate that $A_{21} = A_{12}^T$

Comment: @WillJagy,I don't understand is that a property of the matrix being Symmetric and positive definite?

Comment: Do you want to allow $$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
9&3& 1 \\
3&7&2 \\  \hline
1&2& 11 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: @WillJagy, 

I see. No, they have to be the same dimensions. So I do not allow this, if this is not allowed are you saying that some how $$A_{21} = A_{12}^{\top}? $$

Comment: Your original matrix $A$  is not symmetric unless blocks $A_{11}, A_{22}$ are symmetric and $A_{21}= A_{12}^T$

Comment: @WillJagy, How foolish of me. Yes, I forgot about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\|A\|_2$ refers to the spectral norm of $A$ (the maximal singular value of $A$).

Your statement does not hold. As an example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/4 & 0\\0 & 1/4}, \quad L = \pmatrix{1/2 & 0\\0 & 1/2}.
$$

It is generally true that $\|L_{22}\|_2 \leq \sqrt{\|A\|_2}$. We can see this as follows. Denote
$$
L = \pmatrix{L_{11} & 0\\L_{21} & L_{22}}.
$$
We will use the following two facts:

1. $\|A\|_2 = \|L^TL\|_2 =  \|L\|_2^2$
2. $\|L\|_2 = \max_{\|x\| = \|y\| = 1} x^TLy$.

With that, we note that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\|A\|_2} &= \|L\|_2 = \max \{x^TLy: \|x\| = \|y\| = 1\}
\\ & = \max \Bigg\{ \pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2}^T \pmatrix{L_{11} & 0\\ L_{21} & L_{22}}\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}:
\\ & \qquad \qquad \|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2 = \|y_1\|^2 + \|y_2\|^2 = 1\Bigg\}
\\ & \geq \max
\left\{\pmatrix{0\\ x_2}^T \pmatrix{L_{11} & 0\\ L_{21} & L_{22}}\pmatrix{0\\y_2}:\|x_2\|^2 = \|y_2\|^2 = 1\right\}
\\ & = \max \{x_2^TL_{22}y_2 : \|x_2\| = \|y_2\| = 1\} = \|L_{22}\|.
\end{align}